# Address validation at the time of user input

Tags: java, jsp

I have a signup from where user need to input their address with pin and city. All are text fields.I want to validate those address given by the user.
Means if a user given some wrong address then an error message will prompt saying address is not valid.
Is there any API so that I can validate the address before user data save on the database.

I am going through this link :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key
but it was not free.

After lot of searching I can see that from `smartystreets.com` we can check if a address is valid or not.
But it is paid service and for free service only '250 hits' is eligible per month.
But when I try to call the api from postman I am not getting any response.

API Link:

```
https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/international-street-api?auth-id=a9e4cd62-78df-be45-5575-65efdb06edf5&auth-token=7YEnKXJD7h20yHDfOfra&country=India&address1=DLF2%20Building&locality=Newtown&postal_code=700056
```

[image]

Comment: providing a sample of your code and more information, you will get better answers to your question. I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of answers you receive.

Comment: If you are looking for Address Verification Guide Then I must suggest you, you should start googling it and try it by applying some code and if you face any exception then post your question with some code you've applied with the exception. You can start with [address-verification-guide](https://www.easypost.com/address-verification-guide/java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Geocoding API by google ,you can pass the address to it and if the address is valid then you will get valid geocordinates else not and you can use it as a bypass trick.
Here is the link [GEOCODING API by GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#Geocoding)